# Allow faults in typing

Tags: javascript

I want to make a quiz and the user should type the right answer.
Let's say the answer is correct if the answer matches 90%. For example, if the user types

`Britney Spers` instead of `Britney Spears`, the answer should be right.

I searched for Javascript functions to determine how accurate the answer is, I found some interesting functions for PHP, Ruby etc, but I need it in JavaScript.

Has anybody experience with these kind of algorhitms?
Thank you if you answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the **[edit distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance)** (aka Levenshtein distance). Under this scheme, the *distance* between two strings is the number of *insertions*, *deletions*, or *substitutions* required to make the strings match. For example, if the right answer is "oranges", then:

- "oranges" has a distance of 0 (they are the same word)
- "orange" has a distance of 1 (delete `s`)
- "roranger" has a distance of 2 (insert `r`, substitute `s -> r`)
- "sponges" has a distance of 3 (substitute `o -> s`, substitute `r -> p`, substitute `o -> a`)
- "" has a distance of 7 (insert every letter in `oranges`)

A simple algorithm for it in Javascript would look like this (adapted and modified from **[this gist](https://gist.github.com/982927)**):

```
function(a, b){
  // Return the number of characters in the other
  // string if either string is blank.
  if(a.length == 0) return b.length; 
  if(b.length == 0) return a.length; 

  // Otherwise, let's make a matrix to represent the possible choices
  // we can take.
  var matrix = [];


  var i;
  for(i = 0; i <= b.length; i++){
    matrix[i] = [i];
  }

  var j;
  for(j = 0; j <= a.length; j++){
    matrix[0][j] = j;
  }

  for(i = 1; i <= b.length; i++){
    for(j = 1; j <= a.length; j++){
      if(b.charAt(i-1) == a.charAt(j-1)){
        matrix[i][j] = matrix[i-1][j-1];
      } else {
        matrix[i][j] = Math.min(matrix[i-1][j-1] + 1, // substitution
                                Math.min(matrix[i][j-1] + 1, // insertion
                                         matrix[i-1][j] + 1)); // deletion
      }
    }
  }

  return matrix[b.length][a.length];
};
```

One problem with your question is that the examples you wrote about what you're looking for (e.g. "matches 90%" or "accuracy of the answer") are not well-defined metrics.

There are a lot of ways an answer can be wrong. For example, let's say the right answer is "apple". Which of these should be accepted?

- "APPLE" (wrong capitalization)
- "ppple" (misspelled)
- "apples" (plural, but you wanted the singular)
- "Fuji apple" (too specific)
- "fruit" (too broad)

and so on. Deciding which of these should be accepted is beyond the power of a simple edit-distance algorithm and will require heavier lifting, like NLP.

Comment: Thanks! This works surprisingly good! I will accept it in 5 min.

Comment: It is a music-only based quiz and I will make it case-insensitive, so there shouldn't be a lot of problems with it.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for an edit distance algorithm. Basically, you want to see how many character changes (add/delete/replace) it will take to get from one string to another.  Of course now you have to have a dictionary of target strings to find the distance to.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance

More specifically : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

The edit distance between `Britney Spers` and `Britney Spears` would be one: insert `'a'`.